# Displaying avatar of a user

Tags: avatar

I would like to display the avatar of a user.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/99nOA.jpg
I want to do custom styling, such as the circled avatar.

I have read there is code, and I am assuming this is the one I am wanting to use, I am not exactly sure where the code is supposed to go.

```
<?php
    global $current_user;
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ):
        get_currentuserinfo();     
        echo get_avatar( $current_user->ID, 64 );
    endif;  
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey pass the current user email id in get_avatar() function if user is logged in like this.

```
<?php 
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( ($current_user instanceof WP_User) ) {
        echo get_avatar( $current_user->ID, 32 );
    }
}
```

Comment: I apologize for my novice skill sets, but where exactly do I add that?

Comment: @/ron-martine visit link:-https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-change-the-default-gravatar-on-wordpress/